# Risk of view any definition, view server state

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permissions

What is the risks of giving `view any definition` and `view server state` permission to a user who has windows authentication and `dbcreator` role?

Comment: Well, as the permissions imply, such a user could view all the source code for your triggers and procs.  If you don't want that to happen, then you need to be more restrictive with your rights.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the SQL Server database permissions [poster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-hierarchy-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#chart-of-sql-server-permissions) in order to get a glimpse of the security hierarchy. For example, for the `dbcreator` role you [have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017):

> Members of the dbcreator fixed server role can create, alter, drop,
>   and restore any database.

And from the poster (check the Server Level Permissions for SQL Server table):

- ALTER ANY DATABASE - See Database Permission Charts
- CREATE ANY DATABASE - See Top Level Database Permissions

Basically, you can do anything with each database. And from the same table, for `VIEW ANY DEFINITION` you have:

[image]

But you should already have this, as you have the top level database permissions. The `VIEW SERVER STATE` expands the rights of the `dbcreator role` as you can see from the same table in the poster:

[image]

You can see it is part of the rights of the `serveradmin role`, and gives you `SELECT` rights on server-level DMS's. Also, it gives you `VIEW DATABASE STATE` permission:

[image]

But you should already have access to the database-scoped dynamic management views and functions. So, the new is the access to the server-scoped [ones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/system-dynamic-management-views?view=sql-server-2017):

> There are two types of dynamic management views and functions:
>
> - Server-scoped dynamic management views and functions. These require VIEW SERVER STATE permission on the server.
> - Database-scoped dynamic management views and functions. These require VIEW DATABASE STATE permission on the database.